# TipTap and Nuxt - Can't import the named export '{module}' from non EcmaScript module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use [TipTap](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap) with [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) but can't seem to figure out why it won't work. I've read issues on the repo and used their suggestions but I just get these errors:

```
ERROR  in /Volumes/Projects/nuxt/candy-hub-lerna/node_modules/prosemirror-state/dist/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'ReplaceStep' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR  in /Volumes/Projects/nuxt/candy-hub-lerna/node_modules/prosemirror-view/dist/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Selection' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR  in /Volumes/Projects/nuxt/candy-hub-lerna/node_modules/prosemirror-transform/dist/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Slice' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

**Set up**
My set up is pretty simple and echoes [this github issue](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/issues/131)

```
/components/forms/RichText.vue
```

```
<template>
  <no-ssr>
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
  </no-ssr>
</template>

<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'

export default {
  components: {
    EditorContent
  },
  data () {
    return {
      editor: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.editor = new Editor({
      content: '<p>This is just a boring paragraph</p>'
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    // Always destroy your editor instance when it's no longer needed
    this.editor.destroy()
  }
}
</script>
```

```
/components/global/LocalisedAttributes.vue
```

```
<template>
<div>
    <rich-text />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RichText from '~/components/forms/RichText.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    RichText
  }
}
</script>
```

I've tried adding 'prosemirror-view' and 'tiptap' to build.transpile array in nuxt.config.js but it hasn't had any effect.

If anyones got it working on Nuxt I'd be grateful for any insight in to their set up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with Lerna, I've switched to yarn workspaces and now things seem to be working!

Comment: I wish someone could supply a workaround though, it would be quite a daunting task to switch over all my npm scripts into a yarn workspace